# Specify containerd version on minikube or kind

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kind

I am trying to reproduce an issue that requires me to use containerd v1.4.4 for my container-runtime and kubernetes v1.19.8. When I try to use minikube to create a multi-node cluster locally, it allows me to specify the kubernetes version but I am unable to specify the containerd version(i.e. it always uses v1.4.9) and based on this github [discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6432), it doesn't seem to support it. I then turned to kind but was unable to find a way to specify the same from the documentation. Is there a way either in kind or in minikube to specify the containerd version?

Comment: this should be doable with `containerdConfigPatches`, but I have not tried this myself; for `kind` that is

Comment: Are `minikube` and `kind` the only options you want to use?

Comment: They seemed like the simplest to use but I am open to other options as well

Comment: I ended up using kubeadm with 2 VMs. It would be still be useful to know if there's a way to specify versions in minikube or kind

Comment: It seems in kind you can [build your own base image](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/tree/main/images/base) with specified containerd version. Did you try this maybe?

Comment: Oh interesting, this seems useful! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using kubeadm and set up a master and worker node using 2 VMs. This allowed me to specify the versions I want on the worker node. [Building a base image on kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/tree/main/images/base) should also work as user Mikolaj.S mentioned